# How to show only available geom_segment values in a facet_grid() in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a swimmerplot using `facet_grid()` in `ggplot`, that displays the `time` per `id`.

I managed to visualize the data with the code below. Using `facet_grid()` I was able to differentiate the `IDs` that have a `time>100` vs. `time<=100`.

```r
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(id=seq(1,15,1),
                 time=c(50, 101, 45, 35, 200, 78, 30, 149, 156,58, 39, 10, 65, 38, 20), 
                 test = c(F,T,F,F,T,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F))
# Swimmerplot
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=id, xend=id, y=0, yend=time), size = 4) +
  facet_grid(test~.) +
  coord_flip()
```

Here is the output produced, 
[image: sample_output]

As can be seen from the output, every `id` is shown in both facets.

**Question**

I would like to show only the IDs that have an 'available' time value per facet_grid. How do I do that in `ggplot`? Is `geom_segment` the proper geom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you want (just add `scales = "free", space = "free"`) which does the magic of removing unused factors from the facets.

```r
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=as.factor(id), xend=as.factor(id), y=0, yend=time), size = 4) +
  facet_grid(test~., scales = "free", space = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

## Output

[image: Output_desired]

Comment: The answer, combined with the suggestion from @yoland (`as.factor(id)`, is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You should store `id` as a factor or character vector. Also I think, it is more straigforward to use `geom_bar()` with `stat = "identity"`. It's not pretty, but this does what you want I think:

```
df <- data.frame(id=seq(1,15,1),time=c(50, 101, 45, 35, 200, 78, 30, 149, 156,58, 39, 10, 65, 38, 20), test = c(F,T,F,F,T,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(id), y=time)) +
  geom_bar(size = 4, stat = "identity", na.rm = T) +
  facet_wrap(~test, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
  coord_flip()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution i found for what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(data=df) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=time), size = 4, stat = "identity") +
 facet_grid(test~., scales = "free") +
 coord_flip()
```

`as.factor` changes `id` into a categorical variable, and `scales=free` allows the facets to have different scales, so they now have only the values of `id` with data in their facet.

This solution didn't work with `geom_segment` but did for `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")`